# Change tab color when there is a span present inside a div

Tags: html, css

I have a two different tabs which has the following HTML code,

```css
.tabs{
    margin-left: 10px;
    color: black;
    width: 100%;
}
.all-tab{
    margin-left: 15px;
}
.first-tab{
    margin-left: 0%;
}
.tab {
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 13%;
}
.tab-left {
    float: left;
    width: 17px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 1px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    background-color: #686868;
    transform: skew(-20deg);
}
.tab-centre {
    float: left;
    margin-left: -12px;
    line-height: 30px;
    width: 90%;
    background-color: #686868;
    text-align: center;
    color:white;
}
.tab-right {
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    margin-left: -7px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 1px;
    background-color: #686868;
    transform: skew(20deg);
}
```

```html
<ul class="tabs" role="tablist">
    <div class="all-tab" data-tab="details">
        <span class="tab-left"></span>
        <span class="tab-centre"><li><a class="active" id="btn1" href="#">ALL</a></li></span>
        <span class="tab-right"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="tab first-tab" data-tab="details">
        <span class="tab-left"></span>
        <span class="tab-centre"><li><a class="first" id="btn2" href="#">first</a></li></span>
        <span class="tab-right"></span>
    </div>
</ul>
```

When I click on first tab it should change the color of both the text and the entire tab until the next tab is selected. I've tried differenty CSS combinations but it was of no use. Is there a way that span inside div can change color?

Comment: Have you considered using javascript/ jQuery to detect the click and add a class?

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to fix your Html structure, when wrapping the elements with 'ul' the immediate children of the element must be li.
2. The best solution is to wrap the content inside each li with 'a' element, then even if you click on span it will affect the wrapper DIV.
3. Look at the following example that shows you how to give a different design to each element inside 'a' when clicking on the element.
4. to keep the element mark you better use Javascript in order to mark the focused elements(Add a class to the clicked li).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
      a:focus{
      background:red;
    }
    a:focus div{
    height:20px;
    background:red;
    }
      a:focus span{
    color:yellow;
    }
    a:active{
      background:red;
    }
    a{
      background:blue;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<ul class="tabs" role="tablist">
  <li>
   <a href="#" class="active">
    <div>
     <span>first</span>  
    </div>  
   </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a  href="#">
      <div>
        <span>second</span>  
      </div>
    </a>
 </li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```